# winform app launched at startup, listening in one port, and multiple users problems

Tags: c#, winforms, session, rdp

im facing an architecture question which i don't know how to solve it, so maybe you will have better ideas than me

I have a webapp (blazor but it doesn't matter) deploy on my clients site. This webapp need sometimes calling an installed app to realize some operation which need more right (for example reading some security card which can be connected with an adapter and an USB port).

So for that, my users download a winforms app (.net core 7), packaged in a self extracting zip executable. When they install this local app, this app first registrer itself in CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, and then listen to localhost on the 5100 port.

To communicate with this local app, the webapp make call to the webapi exposed through localhost:5100. The local app react to that, make some opérations, show some interfaces, and return datas.

until there, the things going right. The problems start when there is multiple users on the machine. I have this case specifically for some clients who don't run the webapp through a classic windows on a computer but who are connected to a server  through TSE/RDP. so basically, when they install this local app, it install it to the server.
So lets say a user1 start his session, install the local app, launch the webapp, he can communicate with it.
lets say after a user2 start his session, launch the webapp, he will be totally able to communicate with here. But the problem is when a User interface will pop, it will be launch on the session/screen of User1 !

The good idea to solve that is to remove the user interfaces from the local app, putting them on the webapp, and it will solve everything. Unfortunately, it can't be done with a huge amount of work/refactoring, with a hight risk of regressions, so this solution is the last one we want for now.

I was thinking maybe when i have my form.show() in the code I can target a user session, but it seem unlikely.

I was thinking also make my local app installed for each user, but in this case how I can deal with the fact they will all listen on the same ports ? the first user connected will be able tu run the app but for the other it will failed because the port is already in use !

I ran out ideas, thanks for your help !